# How to create link from Codeigniter form?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to transfer two variables which user inputs into a form but I need to send all data together to database. I can't use `$this->input->post` or `$_REQUEST`, I need to create link like `www.xxx.com/controler?var1=xx*&var2=xx`.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php if($this->input->get_post('tip', TRUE) =='3') {?>
<input type="hidden" name="var_plati" id="var_plati" value="https://www.example.com/beta/tesst/credit-card-reservation-form?tour=<?php echo $_REQUEST['tour'] ?>&tip=<?php echo $_REQUEST['tip'];?>&c=<?php echo $this->input->post("var_charter"); ?>&ad=<?php echo THIS I NEED?>&dep=<?php echo $_REQUEST['var_dep'] ?>" >
```

Comment: Actually, you can use post - place these vars as arguments in processing function, and use url helper to get them. And, you can make segmented (typical CI) URL, right? If you really need GET vars - you can allow it in CI config, but i am not sure that you really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method1: you can use as href link with variables
for eg:

```
<a href="approve.php?id=<?php echo $sub->id ?>" role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a>
```

method2:sending a variable to the codeigniter controller using ajax call

```
 var string_array="&tour="+<?php echo $_REQUEST['var1'] ?>+"&tip="+<?php echo $_REQUEST['var2'] ?>+"&c="
                                +<?php echo $this->input->post("var_charter"); ?>+"&ad="+<?php echo 'THIS I NEED'?>+"&address="+address+"&short_address="+short_address
                                +"&dep="+<?php echo $_REQUEST['var_dep'] ?>;
                             $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "<?php echo site_url('https://www.example.com/beta/learning/reservation-form');?>",
                                        data:string_array,
                                        success: function(msg) {
                                            console.log(msg);
                                        }
                                        });

                                }
```